# haskell-mode emacs not finding modules when using stack

Tags: haskell-mode

Haskell mode doesn't seem to be resolving the modules in emacs when I use the [stack](https://github.com/commercialhaskell/stack) command to build my project.

Is there a file that I have to edit to tell haskell-mode where to find the packages that stack installs from stackage?

Answer (score 3):

All you (should) need to do is insert the following line in your emacs config:

`(setq haskell-process-type 'stack-ghci)`

That tells emacs that you want to use stack's repl command instead of whatever haskell-mode tries to infer automatically for you.

Comment: or use [`intero`](https://github.com/commercialhaskell/intero) :) 
it's extremely simple to set up intero